# How to read a file from resource folder as FileInputStream in JAR Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to read values from a json file which I have placed in my resource folder directly. I am able to run it successfully without any error in bootrun & also build successfully within IntelliJ with the below code

```
 try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream=new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/mockData.json");) {
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Issue with the credential reader"+e.getMessage());

        }
```

However when a JAR is created with the above, I am getting exception as fileNotFound

java -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar

````
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\mockData.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.exampleBQ.demoBQ.BQConfig.getBQBean(BQConfig.java:31)
    ```

Could someone plz help on how to read the file as FileInputStream  within Jar
````

Comment: You don't. You use `Class.getResource()` and friends. You don't have any actual need in this code for `FileInputStream` specifically.

Comment: Thanks @user207421 for your valuable input
This worked for me:    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mockData.json");

Comment: Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:data.txt");
File file = resource.getFile();
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Springboot you can use **Resource** abstraction

Try doing this:-

```
@Value("classpath:mockData.json")
Resource resourceFile;
```